# Is it better to try to get high level skills as soon as possible or is it better to complete the tree circle by circle?

Tags: book-of-hours

In book of hours is it better to try to fill in one track by upgrading skills that go in that track or is it better to follow each track equally? The former seems useful for getting high ranked skills to read complex books but the latter yields far more attributes.